# In Excel, I want specific text in between specific Characters "-"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im Having one Problem, can any one solve this?

I want specific text in between specific Characters "-"

Like

```
1.Individual-Peter-Total
2.Individual-John-Total
3.Society-Paul raj-Total
4.Others-Mitchell-Total
```

all these in different columns, Now I want text in between "-" in another column.

Like

```
1.Peter
2.John
3.Paul raj
4.Mitchell
```

is there any possibility ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  I would suggest using FIND to determine the positions of the two "-"'s, and then use those values to determine the arguments for the MID function in order to return the desired results.  If a non-formula solution is acceptable, just use the Data/Text-to-columns wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that it will always be `-` as the special character and it will always be *something-* **text_you_want** *-something*, then you can use the following formula.  It assumes that your combined column is in **A1** and this formula will be in cell **B1**.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest may be select relevant range, Find `-Total`, Replace with *nothing*, Replace All, then Find `*-`, Replace with *nothing*, Replace All.